Calling .then within a new Promise() javascript
I've learned javascript async/await before learning promise.then() syntax, and I am now attempting to go back and learn promise.then().
I currently have the following code
let getDatabaseData = async () => {
    let res1 = await dbQuery()
    let res2 = await dbQuery2(res1)
    return res1 + res2
}

let dbData = await getDatabaseData()
console.log(dbData)

I want to translate this to promises, and have done so below
let getDatabaseData = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        dbQuery().then(res1 => {
            dbQuery2(res1).then(res2 => {
                resolve(res1 + res2)
            })
        })
    })
}

getDatabaseData().then(dbData => {
    console.log(dbData)
})

Is this the most effective way to do so? I was looking into promise chaining, but it doesn't exactly get me what I want because I want getDatabaseData to act as a helper method to combine the results from dbQuery and dbQuery2

I think you can remove the wrapping promise and return the chain, and just return inside the innermost then()

classic Promise anti-pattern

Aren't promises just callbacks? + What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?

@AndyRay You are right, but I have to return the outer promise and the inner promise. If I do this, won’t I be returning a promise object whos value is a promise object? My code seems to work as expected (console.logging correctly) but I’m not sure why

Your code most directly translates (to me) to:
let getDatabaseData = () => {
    // we can store intermediate values in the closure if we want
    let val1;
    return dbQuery().then(val => {
        val1 = val;
        return dbQuery2(val);
    }).then(val2 => val1 + val2)
}

getDatabaseData().then((data) => console.log(data))

Another option without using the enclosing fn's scope could look like this:
let getDatabaseData = () => dbQuery()
      // here, we use Promise.all to proxy values forward
      // in the resultant promise
      .then(val => Promise.all([val, dbQuery2(val)]))
      .then(([val1, val2]) => val1 + val2)

Remember, any time you're using the new Promise(...) syntax, and calling proimse-generating functions inside that promise, you're probably doing something that could be better accomplished with promise chaining.

It seems like I can also go with my original code, and remove the outermost promise constructor. I then just have to return the outermost promise, then inner promise, and the res1 + res2 and it works as expected. I’m confused though, as I thought this would result in returning a Promise wrapped in a Promise, but I seem to be able to console log the value just fine. Does this return a promise wrapped in a promise? If so, why does my console log print out val1 + val2 and not a promise whos value is val1 +val2?

Promises are unwrapped until they don't give back a promise, so resolving a promise with another is fine and normal. Any code that has an "inner promise" and "outer promise" is dipping its toes into callback hell for convenience imo (which was always the case, callback hell isn't even needed with callbacks, it's just way easier/faster/simpler than writing trampolines)

You can do it without the need for creating a new Promise(), an extra variable or using Promise.all() if you simply nest the dbQueries using the .then() method:


// I am setting up a testing scenario here:
const [dbQuery,dbQuery2]=["posts","users"].map(t=>id=>fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${t}/${id}`).then(r=>r.json())),

// This is the actual function:
  getDatabaseData = pid =>
   dbQuery(pid).then(p =>
     dbQuery2(p.userId).then(u =>
       `Post ${p.id}: "${p.title}" by ${u.name}`
     )
   );

// Now, test the function in an async IIFE:
(async ()=>
  console.log(await getDatabaseData(1+Math.floor(100*Math.random())))
)();



This gives me full access to the results from both queries in a local scope under the objects p (post) and u (user).
